# How many repositories is too many?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

We are getting ready to modularize a large enterprise application that is currently using a dying stack of technologies. My question is in the Repository/Unit of Work pattern, how many Repositories can you have in a unit of work? Say for example we create a UnitOfWork on a single DbContext that exposes 50+ repository entities. Will this cause performance problems?

We were looking at maybe splitting it up so that each schema has it's own DbContext but this seems to add a lot of complexity and then doesn't allow for easy joining of data between the schemas. I feel like creating everything under one context/unit of work is the best answer for ease of use and maintainability but I am concerned performance may be a problem.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly AppContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(AppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Courses = new CourseRepository(_context);
        Authors = new AuthorRepository(_context);
        ...
        ...            
        // Will lots of repositories here cause a performance problem?
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public ICourseRepository Courses { get; private set; }
    public IAuthorRepository Authors { get; private set; }
    ...
    ...

    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `UoW` and `Repository` pattern in `Entity Framework`. EF already implements these patterns.

Comment: That is true but in a large scale enterprise applications a repository/UoW pattern can still be useful to create a proxy layer encapsulating all code dealing with the ORM so that the application is not directly exposed to the ORM. This creates very clean separation of concerns allowing for an easier transition to another ORM down the road without changing any application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a few years old now but I've used a UnitOfWork with a GenericRepository and not suffered any major performance issues. This is hooked into over 100 DB tables of a busy website. 
That said, the website in question also employs the Dapper Micro-ORM throughout as it's very fast and gives more control on complex operations. For CRUD though, the setup below works well for me.

**Unit Of Work**

```
public class UnitOfWork :IDisposable
{
    private DbContext _db = new DbContext();

    private GenericRepository<Table1> table1Repository;
    private GenericRepository<Table2> table2Repository;
    private GenericRepository<Table3> table3Repository;
    ...
    private GenericRepository<TableN> tableNRepository;

    public GenericRepository<Table1> Table1Repository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.table1Repository == null)
            {
                this.table1Repository = new GenericRepository<Table1>(_db);
            }
            return table1Repository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Generic Repository**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity :class
{
    internal DbContext _db;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext _db)
    {
        this._db = _db;
        this.dbSet = _db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query);
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (_db.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        _db.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

List<Table1> list = unitOfWork.Table1Repository.Get(n => n.addedOn <= DateTime.Now);

Table1 item = unitOfWork.Table1Repository.GetById(1);

unitOfWork.Table1Repository.Insert(object);
unitOfWork.Save();

unitOfWork.Table1Repository.Update(object);
unitOfWork.Save();

unitOfWork.Table1Repository.Delete(1);
unitOfWork.Save();

unitOfWork.Table1Repository.Delete(object);
unitOfWork.Save();
```

Comment: This is one of the best ways to manage the costs associated with this pattern, as the individual repository is ONLY created if it is used