# Unit Of Work and dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement Unit Of Work design pattern in my project and from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  the dbContext and all repositories are initialized in the  UnitOfWork class , and I saw there is no place for dependency injection here . Is there is a way to use dpendency injection or there is no need and why?

Comment: If you will be using Entity Framework, then you can skip `UnitOfWork` and repositories.

Comment: Hi - please see my answer here for UoW/Generic Repository. I've been using this way for a while and it works brilliantly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523150/how-many-repositories-is-too-many/49523560#49523560

Comment: @scgough thanks , I have fears about  if this way is going to work fine or I will have a lot of problems .

Answer (score 1):

You can create the DI if you want.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private ISchoolContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(ISchoolContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }    
}
```

Then in your controller you can inject the Unit of Work too in the same way.

You can do all that stuff, now the question is if you need that fancy DI, personally I would, but that is up to you and your needs.

Comment: instead of  private SchoolContext _context; it should be  private ISchoolContext _context;

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation of unit of work if you are using DbContext :

```
class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
   private readonly DbContext _yourDbContext; 

   public UnitOfWork(DbContext yourDbContext)
   {
      _yourDbContext = yourDbContext
   }

   public void Save()
   {
       _yourDbContext.Save();      
   }

   void Dispose()
   {       
       _yourDbContext = null;   
   }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Save();    
}
```

---

Uses :

```
IUnitOfWork _uow;

_yourStudentRepository.Add(Student);
_yourAddressRepository.Add(Address);
_uow.Save();
```